# Laptop does not autorotate in Ubuntu 16.04 Gnome

Tags: 16.04, touchscreen, hybrid, display-rotation

My laptop is an Acer R3 131T. I installed Ubuntu 16.04 Gnome on it. However it does not autorotate the screen when I rotate the laptop. Autorotate worked perfectly fine on Windows 10. Gnome shows the symbol to autorotate or keep screen rotation fixed in the top right menu ( just beside the Settings button) - however when I rotate the screen, autorotate does not work. There is no option for rotation even in Display ( in Settings).  Please help.

Comment: What is the output of (in a termial) `gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.touchscreen orientation-lock`

Comment: @JacobVlijm The output is false

Comment: Ah sorry, misread the comment. removed my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same laptop, running on Debian Stretch (kernel 4.9)

While debugging this, switch to a virtual console with CTRL+ALT+F3 and sign in. Your screen should be the right way round. From here, follow your distribution-specific instructions to upgrade the kernel (`sudo apt install --install-recommends linux-image-generic-hwe-16.04` for Ubuntu 16.04)

I found [this page](https://github.com/hadess/iio-sensor-proxy#known-problems) which explains the issue.

Upgrading the kernel fixed my issue (which was that the sensor was unreliable; it only worked one in a hundred times, and my screen was stuck sideways!)

I hope this solves your issue!